# How do I automatically respawn GNOME Do when it crashes?

Tags: gnome-do

I use, and love, GNOME Do. Sometimes, though, it crashes and I have to re-run it from the menu. Is it possible to set up my GNOME session to automatically try to respawn Do?

I realize there are some caveats contemplating this - if my system gets into a state where Do cannot run at all, this would create an infinite loop of respawning, crashing, and respawning again, but in my experience Do crashes just enough for it to be slightly annoying, and never right after I restart it manually.

If someone can make a case for this being a bad idea, I'd consider that a good answer as well.

Comment: possible duplicate http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com/questions/4628/gnome-do-stops-working

Comment: you may want to troubleshoot the problem instead of just working around it. There is a discussion already about it in the question I mention above. If the problem cannot be solved, personally I would bind a keyboard shortcut to restart Gnome-Do, although you seem to be looking for a more automated solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to start it with a bash script that's basically "while(1){gnome-do}", ensuring that when gnome-do crashes, it gets run again. As long as gnome-do is run synchronously, it should work just fine. even if the system gets into a state where it can't be launched successfully, the impact would be small. If you want to ensure that even that is not a problem, insert a command using zenity. This would notify you that there was a problem, and require you to hit enter to start gnome-do again.

create a script with the following and launch it from the "Startup Applications" application found under the System Preferences menu.

```
while true
do
  gnome-do
  zenity --info --text="gnome-do crashed ... press enter to restart"
done
```

Comment: That was a clever idea. I modified your script to the following: 

<code>`while true; do
  gnome-do 2>> /home/username/gnome-do.log
  if [ "$?" -ne "0" ]; then
    notify-send --urgency=low --icon=gnome-do "GNOME-Do has crashed." "The cause of the crash has been logged to ~/gnome-do.log."
  else
    break
  fi
done`</code>

Assuming that GNOME-Do exits with a non-zero exit code upon crashing, the script should notify me with a notification bubble and restart GNOME-Do. If I exit Do normally, it won't be restarted (if I ever want to get rid of it temporarily). STDERR goes to a log for debugging.

Comment: (It would appear I suck at formatting comments, but you get the gist of it)

Comment: I do, excellent idea, I think I'll actually run it myself.